# Not able to send messages to kafka topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka, Play as well as Scala.
This is my code , where i want to send messages to kafka server,Topic name is "**test-topic**" .
i am not getting any error though i haven't seen my sent messages in the topics
is there anything wrong here

```
 import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig
    import java.util.Properties
    import kafka.producer.Producer
    import scala.util.Random
    import kafka.producer.Producer
    import kafka.producer.Producer
    import kafka.producer.Producer
    import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage
    import java.util.Date

    object KafkaProducerLocal extends App {

      sendMessage

      def sendMessage {

        val topicName = "test-topic"
        try {
          val rnd = new Random()
          val props = new Properties()
          props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092") //kafka 
          props.put("zk.connect", "localhost:2181");  //zookeeper
          props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")
          props.put("producer.type", "async")


          val config = new ProducerConfig(props)
          val producer = new Producer[String, String](config)
          val t = System.currentTimeMillis()
          for (nEvents <- Range(0, 10)) {
            val ip = "192.168.2." + rnd.nextInt(255);
            val data = new KeyedMessage[String, String](topicName, ip, "Swapnil Test Data" + nEvents);
            producer.send(data);
          }

          producer.close();
        } catch {
          case t: Throwable => t.printStackTrace()
        }
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

- Check your log4j properties to view the Logs
- What version of kafka are you running is it the same version as your client.
- Firstly Create a Topic [link](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart_createtopic)
- Check if the server is working and if the topic has been created and you can send and receive messages with the console producer and consumer [example](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart_send)

Application Log

```
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Verifying properties
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Property metadata.broker.list is overridden to localhost:9092
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Property producer.type is overridden to async
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Property serializer.class is overridden to kafka.serializer.StringEncoder
2016-04-19 01:12:34 WARN  kafka.utils.Logging$class:83 - Property zk.connect is not valid
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vishnu/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.12/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vishnu/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Shutting down producer
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Begin shutting down ProducerSendThread
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Fetching metadata from broker id:0,host:localhost,port:9092 with correlation id 0 for 1 topic(s) Set(topic-test)
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Connected to localhost:9092 for producing
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Disconnecting from localhost:9092
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Connected to HMECL001076:9092 for producing
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Shutdown ProducerSendThread complete
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Closing all sync producers
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Disconnecting from HMECL001076:9092
2016-04-19 01:12:34 INFO  kafka.utils.Logging$class:68 - Producer shutdown completed in 298 ms
```

Console Consumer Output

```
 /opt/kafka/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic-test --property group.id cs1 --from-beginning
Swapnil Test Data3
Swapnil Test Data9
Swapnil Test Data2
Swapnil Test Data5
Swapnil Test Data6
Swapnil Test Data8
Swapnil Test Data0
Swapnil Test Data1
Swapnil Test Data4
Swapnil Test Data7
```

Comment: Tried to create topic , its created...thanks fixed !

Comment: props.put("auto.create.topics.enable", "true") added