# KafkaSpout Doesn't consume messages from kafka brokers

Tags: java, hive, hbase, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I developed an application that ingest data in hive and hbase using storm on hdp, the consumer publishes data on a topic but when I run my topology, everything seems okay the topology finally submitted but my kafka spout doesn't consume anything!
I think because of this error:

```
Property zk.connect is not valid                                                                  
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".                                                                                     
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation                                                                                        
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.                                                                   
16/05/07 10:27:09 WARN common.AppInfo$: Can't read Kafka version from MANIFEST.MF. Possible cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: what kafka version you are using how are you building ? Need more log details like how are you passing zk.connect property

Comment: Here is my properties file:

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591731/not-able-to-send-messages-to-kafka-topic/36703102#36703102 where you have similar log message Property zk.connect is not valid